# White papers on logging

Tags: logging

I am planning to create a logging framework for Java/J2EE from scratch.In this regard I want  some white papers on common industry logging standards for reference.Any pointers to the same are appreciated.

Comment: why reinvent a perfectly good wheel?

Comment: Very similar to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673575/what-are-the-best-practices-for-logging-an-enterprise-application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673575/what-are-the-best-practices-for-logging-an-enterprise-application).

Comment: Mitch makes a good point- unless this is a learning excercise you should consider using what's out there.  Log4j is open source, if you don't like something you can change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best resource would be the current Java logging champion- AFAIK that's log4j.

Answer (score 4):

Google 'log4j sucks' or something similar, and try to find out everything you can about what's wrong with the current frameworks.  Since they obviously don't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need another logging framework?

The most commonly used log4j does its job very good and SLF4J is even better.
What do you need that is not in those frameworks?

Comment: log4j doesn't do a good job, It never has. Admittedly when you wrote this answer, it was one of the few options available but still... Not a good job. http://sssslide.com/speakerdeck.com/xorlev/java-logging-ninth-circle-of-hell-a-gentle-introduction-to-java-logging